# Working With Sessions and Captcha

Tags: php, forms, captcha

I am unable to get my sessions captcha to work for some reason.

This is what I currently am trying.

```
$_SESSION['n1'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['n2'] = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $_SESSION['n1']+$_SESSION['n2'];
```

This is what I have in my form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <?=$_SESSION['n1']?> + <?=$_SESSION['n2']?> =
    <input name="captcha" type="text" class="text" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

For some reason it is always returning as the captcha being incorrect.

```
if($_SESSION['expect'] != $_POST['captcha']) {
   $err[] = 'The captcha answer is incorrect.';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are those sessions being created on the same page the form is posting to? Maybe $_SESSION['expect'] is being overwritten with a new value. In that case, it wouldn't equal $_POST['captcha'].

Comment: I think you are right, just not sure where I would need to move the $_SESSION['expect'] so it won't be overwritten.

Comment: You can do something like this: if (!isset($_POST['captcha'])) {//session code}

Comment: Jason, that worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I figured it had to do with them being overwritten, just couldn't figure out an easy way to fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: You could add a if(isset($_POST['captcha'])) to check if it's either creating a captcha or checking a captcha. In case it has failed, you can even create a new one. -- edit - oops just read you answered it

Answer (score 2):

use that order:

```
if($_SESSION['expect'] != $_POST['captcha']) {
  $err[] = 'The captcha answer is incorrect.';
}
```

...

```
$n1 = rand(1,20);
$n2 = rand(1,20);
$_SESSION['expect'] = $n1 + $n2;
```

that way values will not be overwritten

Comment: and what difference will that make?

Comment: Jacek, just by swapping out what I had with your code I still seem to be getting the same results.

Comment: then check what is the value of $_SESSION array on the start of your script

Answer (score 1):

The session is being started, either by [session_start()](http://php.net/session_start) or by [session.auto-start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)-directive?

And are you sure the session id is being passed?

Comment: It is being started by session_start(). Should I put the 
session numbers in the form rather than in the head of the document? I figure like someone said above that the numbers are changing once the form is submitted which is why they do not match up.

Comment: of course you should compare the submitted values to the ones stored in the session before assigning new ones